# Access data returned by getServerSideProps inside Layout in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building a web application using Next.js. It is an admin dashboard for managing multiple tasks where each task has its own SSR page.

**DashboardLayout** :

```js
export const DashboardLayout = ({children}) => {
  const items = [
  {
    href: "/",
    icon: <ChartBarIcon fontSize="small" />,
    title: "Dashboard",
  },
  {
    href: "/tracks",
    icon: <ArtTrackIcon fontSize="small" />,
    title: "Gestion des tracks",
    // I WANT TO ADD NOTIFICATION HERE
  }
  ....
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <DashboardLayoutRoot>
        <Box>
          {children}
        </Box>
      </DashboardLayoutRoot>
      <Box>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <NavItem key={item.title} icon={item.icon} href={item.href} title={item.title} />
          ))}
      </Box>
    </>
  );
  };
```

**tracks.js** :

```js
const Page = ({ tracks }) => {
console.log(tracks);
return(<>....</>)
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
const result =  await axios.get("/track/landing-tracks-for-admin");
return {
      props: {
        tracks: result.data,
      },
    };
}
```

`track.status` can be 'DRAFT' or 'PUBLISHED'. What I want is to show the number of drafted tracks in the layout. It is a kind of notification to indicate that some tracks are not yet published.

The problem is that in the layout `component`, I have no information about the API response; it is called from `getServerSideProps` to provide data to the page.

I don't use redux, and I don't have a provider other than the next-auth session. Do I need to create an endpoint specifically for this or there is another solution? I want the best practice.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, did you check my below answer? Give it a try a let me know please :)

Comment: Hello yousoumar Yes thank you I have check it and I upvoted it seems like a good idea but I think with your solution I can only get the data after calling the page but what I want is to get the data in the layout before the user clicks on the layout to go to the page

Comment: I see, but this would not be possible, as `getServerSideProps` literally runs after you ask for the page, meaning after you navigate to its URL.

Comment: Yes that's why I am thinking of creating an endpoint that returns the number of notifications for every item. make it running inside `useEffect()` and trigger it on every update.

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution. I updated my answer to highlight this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data returned by `getServerSideProps` is passed as `props` to the page. And this same `props` is accessible in `_app.js`, so you can pass it to the layout. As an example like so:

```js
// components/layout.js

import Layout from "../components/layout";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    // here you pass the pageProps to the layout
    <Layout pageProps={pageProps}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

```js
// components/layout.js

export default function Layout({ pageProps, children }) {
  console.log(pageProps);
  return (
    <>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
// pages/index.js

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const result = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await result.json();
  return {
    props: {
      tracks: data,
      /*
        I'm passing this to know the data of which page
        is received in the Layout.
      */
      page: "home",
    },
  };
}
```

The above solution lets you access the data after you visit the URL of that page. If you want data inside the `Layout` without going to the page, you need to make a separate call, like in a `useEffect`:

```
// components/layout.js

import { useEffect } from "react";
import Footer from "./footer";

export default function Layout({ pageProps, children }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetcher() {
      const result = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      const data = await result.json();
      console.log(data);
    }
    fetcher();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}
```